# SQL Server Error "Database 'mssqlsystemresource' does not exist."

Tags: sql-server, linux, connections, system-tables, dac

On Linux, whenever I run `use mssqlsystemresource` to get access to [Resource Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/resource-database), I get an error. How do I resolve this.

```
1> use mssqlsystemresource
2> go
Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Server x230, Line 1
Database 'mssqlsystemresource' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

When I try to log in with `sqlcmd` with DAC (`admin:`) targeting the database with `-d`

```
$ sqlcmd -I -S admin:localhost -U sa -d mssqlsystemresource -P Password0
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Cannot open database "mssqlsystemresource" requested by the login. The login failed..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'sa'..
```

When I try to log in with `mssql-cli`'s `-A`, I get

```
$ mssql-cli -A -d mssqlsystemresource
Username (press enter for sa): 
Password: 

Connection did not succeed.
Error message: Cannot open database "mssqlsystemresource" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'sa'.
Unable to connect. Please try again
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mssqlsystemresource` database is only available in single-user mode. On Linux, that means

```
sudo systemctl stop mssql-server
sudo -u mssql /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr -m
```