# On SQL Server 2017 (Linux), where is the Resource Database persisted (located on disk)?

Tags: sql-server, linux, database-internals, sql-server-2017

In my default install of SQL Server 2017 on Linux, under `/var/opt/mssql/data` I see the following databases,

- `master.mdf` - **master Database** - Records all the system-level information for an instance of SQL Server.
- `model.mdf` - **model Database** - Is used as the template for all databases created on the instance of SQL Server. Modifications made to the model database, such as database size, collation, recovery model, and other database options, are applied to any databases created afterward.
- `msdbdata.mdf` - **msdb Database** - Is used by SQL Server Agent for scheduling alerts and jobs.
- `tempdb.mdf` - **tempdb Database** - Is a workspace for holding temporary objects or intermediate result sets.

All of these databases are [actually pretty well documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/system-databases). However my install's omission of the Resource Database stands out. The description of the Resource Database seems to indicate that it is its own database,

> The Resource database is a read-only database that contains all the system objects that are included with SQL Server. SQL Server system objects, such as sys.objects, are **physically persisted in the Resource database**, but they logically appear in the sys schema of every database. The Resource database does not contain user data or user metadata.

Even more confusing, for [SQL Server 2012 the docs say,](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190940(v=sql.110).aspx) (not 2017 which is what I'm running)

> **Physical Properties of Resource**
>
> The physical file names of the Resource database are mssqlsystemresource.mdf and mssqlsystemresource.ldf. These files are located in `<drive>:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.<instance_name>\MSSQL\Binn\`. Each instance of SQL Server has one and only one associated mssqlsystemresource.mdf file, and instances do not share this file.

I don't see a `mssqlsystemresource.mdf` anywhere though. Where is this database stored? Is this compiled into the server itself?

Checking it out, I [started up database in single-user mode](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/192956/2639) and connected to `mssqlsystemresource` and started digging,

```
1> USE mssqlsystemresource
2> GO
Changed database context to 'mssqlsystemresource'.
1> SELECT type, type_desc, physical_name FROM sys.database_files;
2> GO
type type_desc                                                    physical_name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
---- ------------------------------------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0 ROWS                                                         d:\dbs\sh\s17o\1116_092427_2\cmd\43\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\mssqlsystemresource.mdf                                                                                                                                                        
   1 LOG                                                          d:\dbs\sh\s17o\1116_092427_2\cmd\43\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\mssqlsystemresource.ldf                                                                                                                                                        

(2 rows affected)
```

I don't see these `.ldf` or `.mdf` anywhere though. And, being a Linux install I'm guessing `d:\dbs\sh\s17o\1116_092427_2\cmd\43\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\` is a virtualized internal directory.

Further `sys.master_files` lacks the db too

```
1> SELECT LEFT(name,20), LEFT(physical_name,35) FROM sys.master_files WHERE name LIKE 'ms%';
2> GO

-------------------- -----------------------------------
MSDBData             /var/opt/mssql/data/MSDBData.mdf   
MSDBLog              /var/opt/mssql/data/MSDBLog.ldf    
(2 rows affected)
```

When I start up the database in single user mode `sudo -u mssql /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr -m` I see this,

```
spid9s   Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
spid9s   The resource database build version is 14.00.3008. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've confirmed that this Resource Database is packed in the archive, `/opt/mssql/lib/sqlservr.sfp` along with the rest of the files in `Binn`. So the answer to the question is that it resides in the `sfp` archive. More to the answer, you can [extract that `sfp` with the method here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/192975/2639) creating a new file with the contents,

```
/opt/mssql/lib/sqlservr/Content/binn/mssqlsystemresource.mdf
```

So the contents there are likely virtualized in the In the Drawbridge layer as

```
d:\dbs\sh\s17o\1116_092427_2\cmd\43\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\mssqlsystemresource.mdf
```