# What are these SFP files that SQL Server distributes?

Tags: sql-server, linux, database-internals

What are the SFP files that come with SQL Server 2017?

```
/opt/mssql/lib/sqlservr.sfp
/opt/mssql/lib/sqldkxplat.sfp
/opt/mssql/lib/secforwarderxplat.sfp
/opt/mssql/lib/system.common.sfp
/opt/mssql/lib/system.certificates.sfp
/opt/mssql/lib/system.netfx.sfp
/opt/mssql/lib/system.sfp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out these are packed archive. It's part of the "Platform Abstraction Layer" that hosts the operating system in a library, or "Drawbridge" Library OS. Not much is known about Drawbridge yet, but here is [one resource on Github](https://github.com/thinkcz/DrawBridge) that pointed me over to a tool [`sfpack`](https://github.com/nta/sfpack).

`sfpack` was able to extract these archives.

A quite exhaustive explanation:
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sql-server-on-linux-how-does-it-actually-work